# What does the below Error code mean in power edge R710?

Tags: raid, storage, dell

What does the below error mean

```
unexpected sense,SCSI sense data:Sense Key:3 Sense Code:11 Sense Qualifier:0:Physical Disk 0:0:0 Controller 0,Connector 0

Reset to device,\Device\RaidPort 0 was issued

Command timeout on physical disk: Physical Disk 0:0:0 Controller 0, Connector 0
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, sounds like a corrupted array or drive. Check your drives for health, I bet one of them is faulty.